# Count with CSV using SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, csv, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to count number of records comes under csv column and also want to display them distinct.

**Example**:

Table:

```
create table test1
(
 cola int,  
 colb varchar(10)
)
```

Some records:

```
insert into test1 values(1,'SAM');
insert into test1 values(2,'SAM');
insert into test1 values(3,'JACK');
insert into test1 values(4,'MAK');
```

Script:

```
with cte (colb)
AS
(
   SELECT SUBSTRING(
   (SELECT  ',' + s.colb
   FROM test1 as s
   ORDER BY s.colb
   FOR XML PATH('')),2,200) AS CSV
 )
select count(*) as NumberOfNames,colb as Names
from cte
group by colb
```

Result:

```
NumberOfNames          Names
-----------------------------------
     1            JACK,MAK,SAM,SAM
```

Expected Result:

```
NumberOfNames          Names
-----------------------------------
     3             JACK,MAK,SAM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CTE only concatenates Names and doesn't count them.
Based on your example the query might be like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT colb) AS NumberOfNames,
(SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + s.colb FROM test1 as s ORDER BY s.colb FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')) AS CSV
FROM test1
```

Result:

```
NumberOfNames CSV
------------- ----------------
3             JACK,MAK,SAM,SAM
```

where STUFF function is used to remove the first comma.

Answer (score 0):

How about this....

```
Declare @tempVariable as Varchar(100)
Select @tempVariable= coalesce(@tempVariable+',','')+ colb 
from 
(
    Select distinct colb from  test1
) as te
Select len(@tempVariable) - len(replace(@tempVariable, ',', ''))+1, @tempVariable
```

**Result:**

```
NumberOfNames   CSV
3               JACK,MAK,SAM
```